# From where i can insert field input to odoo database

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

Hello  im  new  in  programming  with  openerp  ODOO  ,  well  my  issue  is  where  i  can  find  the  functions  of  inserting  into  odoo database  ,  well  i  created  a  new  field  and  i  want  to  insert  the  data  of  this  field  into  the  db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like as you said, you are just getting started.

I would advise going through the [following tutorial](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html) for starters.

You need to get an understanding of how Models and Views work in Odoo first and foremost.

Assuming you have added a new field to your model you will need to add this new field to a view for this model.

You will notice that if you have the appropriate permissions you will have an "Edit" and "Save" button (depending on state) on the top left of your views.

[image]
[image]

These buttons are mapped to functions which can be found on your model.

When you define your model you will notice it inherits `models.Model` which adds a lot of functionality that you will need for your model. This includes all [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations. You can overide the default function if needed like so

The CREATE METHOD

```
@api.model
@api.returns('self', lambda rec: rec.id)
def create(self, vals):
    # CUSTOM CODE BEFORE RECORD CREATION
    rec = super(FocusType, self).create(vals)
    # CUSTOM CODE AFTER RECORD CREATION
    return rec
```

THE WRITE METHOD

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    # CUSTOM CODE BEFORE RECORD WRITE 
    result = super(FocusType, self).write(vals)
    # CUSTOM CODE BEFORE RECORD WRITE
    return result
```

Comment: thank u sir for ur explanation , but just one more question , in odoo directory where i can find the files that play a rol of inserting , updating and deleting the data in postgresql databse

Comment: In my installation you can find many examples `/opt/odoo10/odoo/models.py`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store field value in database then add store=True within your field in python file. Then Your value store into database.